# Got error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string" when running a hadoop job in local mode

Tags: hadoop, jobs, illegalargumentexception

I have a hadoop job ran regularly in a test environment in local mode with Hadoop 2.2.0 install. The job succeeds most of the time but fails occasionally with the mentioned error message. The call stack is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:127) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:135) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:94) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:150) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:636) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:430) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286) 
    at com.mathworks.hadoop.MWMapReduceDriver.run(MWMapReduceDriver.java:1443) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84) 
    at com.mathworks.hadoop.MWMapReduceDriver.main(MWMapReduceDriver.java:1454) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

The same job doesn't fail with Hadoop 1.2.1. I looked into the source code of LocalJobRunner.java and found line 150 is as follows:

```
this.localJobDir = localFs.makeQualified(new Path(new Path(conf.getLocalPath(jobDir), user), jobid.toString()));
```

I printed out conf.getLocalPath(jobDir), user and jobid.toString() in an exception catch block and found out user was empty when the job fails. According to the source code, user is obtained with call `UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getShortUserName()`. Does anyone know in what condition this call could return a empty string?